Looking for quote from Seneca Moral Letters
Hopefully I'm not doing much violence to the text/intention or mixing various passages, but in Seneca's Moral Letters (100% there and 95% in a letter number < 100) there is a passage where he says (or brings the complaint of his penpal) something to the effect that some might achieve something easily and without a lot of work. I think the word for achieve/getting/come to them was somewhat notable to me (so not contingere and probably active plural)
can't find it. With keywords I keep reaching letter 88 which is not there.

Seneca Epistulae Morales, one latin text for them, is at  https://www.lateinlex.de/?call=Puc&permalink=Sen_epist which appears to include all letters eg letter 88 with direct link https://www.lateinlex.de/?call=Puc&permalink=Sen_epist_11_88.  An English Translation of the letters is at https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Moral_letters_to_Lucilius  which which appears to include all letters eg letter 88 https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Moral_letters_to_Lucilius/Letter_88

Neither Letter 42, or letter 88, on actual reading appear to have the quote sought. In checking letter 42 with the title in English. On values;  https://www.lateinlex.de/?call=Puc&permalink=Sen_epist_5_42 ,  line 8 the quote was:  Saepe maximum pretium est, pro quo nullum datur.

The English extraction is from https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Moral_letters_to_Lucilius/Letter_119
The Latin extraction is from https://www.lateinlex.de/?call=Puc&permalink=Sen_epist_20_119
Seneca's Letter 119 titled In English 'On nature as our best provider' might possibly be what you seek.
Line 1: I shall lead you by a short cut to the greatest riches
Line 1: ad maximas te divitias conpendiaria ducam.
Line 12: that you should measure all things by the demands of Nature; for these demands can be satisfied either without cost or else very cheaply.
Line 12  ut omnia naturalibus desideriis metiaris, quibus aut gratis satis fiat aut parvo;
Another extract of an English translation of Lines 1, 12 from CLARENDON LATER ANCIENT PHILOSOPHERS, Seneca, Oxford University Press, (c) Brad Inwood 2007
Line 1 I’ll teach you how you can get rich very quickly.
Line 12. to measure all things by one’s natural desires, which can be satisfied for free or for very little

Thanks. this is a nice a quote that relates to what I was looking for. It is not this, but perhaps I was combining two quotes (maybe one for that letter 88: sine liberalibus studiis ad virtutem non perveniri.). I still think it wasn't this. will revist this question if I found it. anyway much thanks for the effort.
